# python multiply all elements except ith element in list and return list

Tags: python, list, multiplication

Suppose I have a `list` .I want to multiply its all elements except with the i'th element.

Example:

- input: [1,2,3,4]
- output: [24,12,8,6]

Here, the output

```
 24 is 2*3*4
 12 is 1*3*4
 8 is 1*2*4
 6 is 1*2*3
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What went wrong?

Comment: Strange to accept an answer that tells the same as me 3 min before him, and better by using `enumerate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution using two for loops:

```
l=[1,2,3,4]
out=[]
for i in range(len(l)):
    prod=1 
    for j in range(len(l)):
        if(j!=i): #Iterate through list once more and compare the indices
            prod=prod*l[j]
    out.append(prod) 
print(out)
```

Output is: `[24, 12, 8, 6]`

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `itertools.combinations` (and reversed to get the right order)

```
from itertools import combinations
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
result = [reduce(mul, c) for c in combinations(reversed(values), r=len(values) - 1)]
print(result)  # [6, 8, 12, 24]
```

Or using your logic directly : iterate and for each index don't use the corresponding value

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
result = []
for i in range(len(values)):
    x = 1
    for idx, value in enumerate(values):
        if i != idx:
            x *= value
    result.append(x)

print(result)  # [24, 12, 8, 6]
```

Comment: You can do `combinations(reversed(values), r=len(values) - 1)`

Comment: Also need to import reduce `from functools import reduce`